# Export and re-import ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two different (very long) R scripts, each ultimately producing two ggplots (p and q).

I want to save these two plots as "gg-files", so that I can re-upload them in a third R script, where I will use ggarrange (or else) to merge them for an academic publication.

How can I export/import ggplots as "gg-objects"?

My apologies for my code - I'm a newbie

Thank you in advance!

I have looked into several methods of saving (e.g. ggsave, svg() def.off(), imager package, rsvg package) but none provided what I am looking for.

```
# script A
rm(list = ls()) # clean environment
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()

svg(filename = "p.svg") # saves as image
p
dev.off()

# script B
rm(list = ls()) # clean environment
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
q <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()

# script C
rm(list = ls()) # clean environment

## import images - how?

## combine

ggarrange(
  p, q,
  nrow = 2
)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can save them like this:

```
xx <- ggplot(mtcars)+geom_histogram(aes(x=cyl))


save(xx, file = "G:/gpl.rdata")
```

Then load them :

```
load("G:/gpl.rdata")
```

This will bring the whole object in and you can see the data used to build the plot and other features of the plot

Comment: Thank you! 

Via another source, I also found that saveRDS() and readRDS() do the trick